# Ruby on Rails Test – Reset/Refresh Validators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, testing

I am writing tests for a RoR Gem that has a validation that is dependent on a configuration variable:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  validates_length_of :field_name, minimum: GemName.minimum_field_length
end
```

I can verify that this configuration option works as expected, however I want to ensure that it is covered in test:

```
class MyModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "field length is validated" do
    model = MyModel(field_name: 'a' * 25

    # Default minimum length is 20
    assert model.valid?

    # Test different length validation
    GemName.minimum_field_length = 30
    assert_not model.valid?
  end
end
```

The second assertion fails (the model is valid). If I add a debugger there and inspect, `GemName.minimum_field_length` gives me `30`, indicating that it is changed, but if I look at the result of `MyModel.validators`, the minimum is still the original default value of 20. Presumably this is because the validators are created once, either when the test starts or when the model is called the first time (I have tried creating a new instance of `MyModel` after changing the config with no luck). Is there a way similar to `.reset_column_information` to refresh the model validators with the new configuration value during the test?

Comment: Mock the configuration return value before running the test

Comment: @dbugger: Good call, haven't touched mocks since my Java testing days. What component would I mock in this scenario? I would think the config variable, since this is the responsibility of the framework and not my code, but how? I don't want to mock the validator, that's what I'm testing. Either way, I'm not sure how to connect the mock to appropriate part of the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that defining a `minimum` length in a validation like this

```
validates_length_of :field_name, minimum: GemName.minimum_field_length
```

then it sets the minimum only once when the file is read for the first time. When `GemName.minimum_field_length` changes, then the configuration of the validator is not changed anymore.

But when you initialize the validator with a lambda instead, then the lambda would be evaluated on every validator call and should therefore pick up changes.

Try this instead:

```
validates_length_of :field_name, minimum: -> { GemName.minimum_field_length }
```

When you only want to ensure that the minimum length of the field equals the gem's configured minimum length, then you might want to write a test that checks if both values are equal, like this:

```
minimum_field_name_length = MyModel.validators_on(:field_name)
                                   .select { |v| v.is_a?(LengthValidator) }
                                   .first
                                   .options[:minimum]

assert_equal minimum_field_name_length, GemName.minimum_field_length
```

Comment: This does work! Would there be any reason, outside of test, to do this? Does the model need to be able to handle a configuration change at any point? Your answer directed me to trying to reload the model file in the test which also solves the problem and feels like a better approach if the lambda isn't used outside the test environment.

Comment: In this case, no. Because the `GemName.minimum_field_length` will not change while the server is running. But I can image examples in which you want the validation to be dynamic. For example, when the maximum length depends on the user's subscription level. Then the configuration needs to load the current maximum length, for example, from the current user.

Comment: And actually, I would argue that you should not test this configuration change at all. Testing that `GemName.minimum_field_length` is returning an expected value is okay. Testing that there is a maximum length validation too. But both methods (the configuration and the validator) are already tested in gems. There isn't really a benefit in testing those methods in your application again, apart from the integration test.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It was starting to get to a complexity where I felt that was testing outside the scope of my code too much. I need some sort of test to verify that the configuration is used in the validation, but I was able to instead rely on removing the class and reloading the file in test to verify that the validators got updated by the config while keeping the validator lambda-free as this app doesn't need dynamic changes.

Comment: @RedBassett I updated my answer with an alternative way to verify that the validator has the same minimum length configured as the gem.